# Manipulations with Lat-Lon and Time Series Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, calculated-columns

I am trying to do some file merging with Latitude and Longitude.

```
Input File1.csv

Name,Lat,Lon,timeseries(n)
London,80.5234,121.0452,523
London,80.5234,121.0452,732
London,80.5234,121.0452,848
Paris,90.4414,130.0252,464
Paris,90.4414,130.0252,829
Paris,90.4414,130.0252,98
New York,110.5324,90.0023,572
New York,110.5324,90.0023,689
New York,110.5324,90.0023,794


File2.csv
Name,lat,lon,timeseries1
London,80.5234,121.0452,500
Paris,90.4414,130.0252,400
New York,110.5324,90.0023,700
```

Now Expected output is

```
File2.csv

Name,lat,lon,timeseries1,timeseries(n) #timeseries is 24 hrs format 17:45:00
London,80.5234,121.0452,500,2103 #Addition of all three values 
Paris,90.4414,130.0252,400,1391
New York,110.5324,90.0023,700,2055
```

With `python, numpy and dictionaries` it would be straight as `key = sum of values` but I want to use `Pandas`

Please suggest me how to start with or may be a point me to some example. I have not see anything like Dictionary types with Pandas with `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html#pandas.Series.groupby) aggregation on the first df, call [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum) and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) this with the other df:

```
In [12]:
gp = df.groupby('Name')['timeseries(n)'].sum().reset_index()
df1.merge(gp, on='Name')

Out[14]:
       Name       Lat       Lon  timeseries1  timeseries(n)
0    London   80.5234  121.0452          500           2103
1     Paris   90.4414  130.0252          400           1391
2  New York  110.5324   90.0023          700           2055
```

the aggregation looks like this:

```
In [15]:    
gp

Out[15]:
       Name  timeseries(n)
0    London           2103
1  New York           2055
2     Paris           1391
```

Your csv files can loaded using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) so something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('File1.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('File2.csv')
```

Comment: This looks great much simpler than usual `Dictionaries`. Thank you so much ..shall put the code together and execute and rely if any doubts.